# Unable to get Alert function to consistently work with backend widget with latest WP

Tags: widgets

I have a back-end widget form that I developed as part as a word-press plugin.  However, the alert boxes are not at all working and I am confused why.  This is a default install of the latest WP with the standard theme that comes with a new installation.  My widget is located at:

http://codesupport.shalomisrael.org/wp-content/plugins/carousel_edit_url_for_newspro_201709181655.zip

Please help!

Debugging steps:

1)  Started with a fresh installation of the latest version of WordPress with GoDaddy Shared hosting, and loaded just the one plugin => issue persists that the alert boxes are not showing the expected values.
2)  Got an example code from w3schools.com located at simpletest.com at the main web-domain.  I can only include 2 links with my current status.
3)  Took a screenshot of the issue.  Basically the value is not being recorded correctly as follows:

[Screenshot of the drop down not working issue] https://codesupport.shalomisrael.org/DropDownBugScreenShot201709191216.jpg

Comment: downvoted as questions should be self contained, and in case of "S is not working" also a description of what debuging steps have you done. please edit and improve the question

Comment: The picture link "Screenshot of the drop down not working issue" is not giving access to the picture currently:  [2]:  https://codesupport.shalomisrael.org/DropDownBugScreenShot201709191216.jpg

Comment: If you need login credentials, please let me know, for the test site.  The test site codesupport.shalomisrael.org is just for debugging purposes.  Also, I tested http://codesupport.shalomisrael.org/simpletest.html which works as expected.  The sourcecode can be retrieved in Firefox 55.0.3 with the menu Tools -> Developer -> Web Source (Control-U)

Comment: For whoever posted a negative vote for the question, please let me know why.  I want to continue to improve the question so that it only receives positive votes if at all possible.

Comment: I updated the test site with the working solution now.  So if you want to see the problem again, you would need to start with a fresh WordPress installation and add my plugin referenced above

Comment: as I explained in the first comment, questions should be self contained If  to be able to answer them you need to download some external code or setup/login to some enviroment, they are just bad questions that are unlikely to get answers and are unlikely to be of any use to anyone else once those resources are removed. Anyway, sounds like you are making progress with your code, so just something to keep in mind for your next question. Shana tova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the name of the back-end widget reference to "carousel_edit_url_for_newspro/backendwnisoform.php" in order to isolate the problem down to its essentials.

The code below works, praise G-d.  I should then be able to use this sort of code in the main stream of the program development to get the drop-down menus to work fine, G-d willing:

```
?><br>
<select id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'myselect' ) ); ?>" onchange="myFunction126(this.id, this.value)">
<option value="Audi">Audi
<option value="BMW">BMW
<option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
<option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'mydemo' ) ); ?>">Hi There!</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction126(thisid126, thisvalue126) {
var x126 = document.getElementById(thisid126).value;
var y126 = thisvalue126;
document.getElementById(id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'mydemo' ) ); ?>").innerHTML 
= "You selected: " + x126;
alert ("New selection!  x126 = " + x126 + " and y126 = " + thisvalue126);
}
</script>
```

For those wanting the latest script that was working correctly (just on this one issue isolated out), it is available from:

[Zip file containing the plugin with the one element working just fine](http://shalomisrael.org/codesupport/wp-content/plugins/carousel_edit_url_for_newspro_201709201551_WorksGreat.zip)

Comment: Note the use of onchange="myFunction126(this.id, this.value)" with both the id and value being passed.  I remember encountering problems if the id *and* the value were not *both* passed.  Be careful with this.  It should not be that difficult to program this stuff, but it currently feels like a bridge over uncharted waters.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please mark your answer as accepted and avoid changing the title to something like _"Resolve! - Title"_.

Comment: I am not seeing the ability for me to mark the answer as accepted when I answer my own question.  How is that done?

Comment: There is a gray checkbox under the vote counts for your answer (left top of the answer). You will be able to mark it as accepted 24 hours after you post your answer.

Comment: I see a gray check box, and I clicked it.  Thank you for the help Jack!