# How do I get both horizontal and vertical scroll bars in an HTML texbox

Tags: infinite-scroll, content-width

I have an issue that I can find how to setup vertical scroll-bars but not horizontal scrollbars.

A couple of demos are at:

https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/tag_textarea.asp 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292559/how-to-scroll-text-area-horizontally

I ran out of references. I am looking to have the box formatted within a table to handle 100% width of the table and the available height.

Comment: I am wanting to use the select box if I can.  The rest of the text inputs are with select boxes, and I would want this to have the same look and feel but support multi-line if possible.

Answer (score 0):

So, with what you explained in the comments, I don't know if I can see what you really need, as to the functions.

If you create a `<textarea>`, you will have multiline for the user to write.

If you create a `<textarea>`, and define `white-space: pre;`, you will have the possibility to have an horizontal bar.

If you create a `<textarea>`, define `white-space: pre;`, and tweak a little with JS, you will get a box, with horizontal scrolling and the possibility of defining a `maxlength` (Like in the example I made: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEJqBj

Comment: I want multi-line input boxes so that the user can type in very long text strings that can be read.  With the Input, I think it might be limited to viewing one line, and it is not easy for the user to adjust this.  With Visual Basic or Visual C++ it is straightforward;  it should be the same for HTML.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer.

Comment: I gave you an up vote, but I need a reputation of at least 15 for that up vote to show was the response that I received.  Also, I added some additional detail to the answer I provided, and I appreciate your commenting about the answer that I provided also.  Thank you for your interest and help!

Comment: I edited my answer. But I'm not sure about the functions you need. If you can, explain the 'flow' of what you need.

Comment: And the extra infos you providade, don't put them as an answer. Edit your question and put them there. It's more organized and makes it easier to understand the 'history'

Comment: Hello Marcelo -- I think your feedback about adding additional information to the question might be good;  however, with my reputation under 10 currently I am not able to fully explain the question or answer without help from someone with a greater reputation needed for such a task.  If you could assist with this, it would be appreciated.  By the way, I did follow your link to the site and it looked impressive.  Thank you for including that too!

Comment: You have enough reputation to edit your own question.

What exactly you need to do, that your current reputation don't allow you?

I looked at your other post, about the widget. And I think you have a few issues going on. You should post one question for each issue. That will keep things organized and will be more likely to get answered.

The best way is to do it in steps. Get the first problem resolved, than create a new question for the second one, and so on.

Comment: And keep in mind that using <input> for multiline text is not possible natively and, if hacked, would be invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_textarea_readonly.asp without the readonly field (to allow writing).

Basically try:

```
    <textarea>
    At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free
    tutorials in all web development technologies.
    </textarea>
```

From the related link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript/1125521#1125521 one can use the onKeyPress event to update downstream content.  For myself, for example, I defined a bunch of text boxes that are updated by other objects in the widget, since it was easier for me to get text boxes to work before the rest could (it was a sure but slow solution).

```
    <textarea onKeyPress="return ( this.value.length < 1000 );" id = "textareaid" rows="4">
    </textarea>
```

Within a backend widget for WordPress the "textareaid" needs to be treated delicately (I have another question about that here, but I do not have enough references available to post that link yet in the answer field.)

Comment: If someone with enough reputation could add in this reference to how the back end widget needs to be formatted in the answer, that would be appreciated!  See:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/280345/resolved-unable-to-get-alert-function-to-consistently-work-with-backend-widge to have the id be properly formatted.